Build on Linux is failed after updating to dotnet-sdk-8.0 (8.0.404)
Installing .NET SDK v8.0.404 breaks the .NET installation and prevents building apps or opening projects in IDEs like Rider.
In the terminal, you may see an error like this:
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.404/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props(14,38): error MSB4242: SDK Resolver Failure: "The SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildWorkloadSdkResolver" failed...


This issue occurs because Microsoft missed something in their package for your OS (I tested on openSUSE).
To resolve it, follow these steps:

Go to the .NET installation directory and locate a path like the following:
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk-manifests/8.0.100/workloadsets


There should be a directory corresponding to the latest .NET 8 version. For now it is 8.0.404-baseline.24523.81. Inside this directory, you can find the file baseline.workloadset.json.

Delete all directories that do not contain such file, in my case it is:


/usr/share/dotnet/sdk-manifests/8.0.100/workloadsets/8.0.401-baseline.24412.2
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk-manifests/8.0.100/workloadsets/8.0.402-baseline.24467.1

These directories were most likely not cleaned up after upgrading to dotnet-sdk-8.0.804.
